# are there any functions in BLAS that can perform skew-symmetric matrix-vector products?

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

I'm thinking of performing some calculations with Intel-MKL, specifically the matrix-vector Sparse BLAS functions for a program in Fortran.

I can express my calculations in matrices that happen to be sparse and skew-symmetric

From what I can see, Sparse BLAS has sparse functions for general and symmetric matrices, so I wanted to know if I there was a way to work with a sparse skew-symmetric matrix instead, because I imagine it would reduce memory footprint.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. BLAS is for dense matrices. Do you mean Sparse BLAS http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node381.html ? Be aware that library recommendations are off-topic here. See also [ask].

Comment: Check https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-c/top/appendix-a-linear-solvers-basics/sparse-matrix-storage-formats/sparse-blas-diagonal-matrix-storage-format.html

Comment: Standard BLAS is for dense matrices and does not contain anything in particular for skew symmetric matrices, so you will have to loo elsewhere

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава hi, yes I meant sparse BLAS. I'll edit the question so this is correct

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I did have a look at the diagonal storage format and how it mentions skew-symmetric matrices, but unfortunately I can't seem to find anything in the manual about any functions for these skew-symmetric matrices

Comment: There wouldn't be any specific functions. Just normal Sparse BLAS functions that accept this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; MKL Sparse BLAS can do matrix-vector multiplications with a sparse matrix expressed as the upper/lower triangle by the [`mkl_scsrmv` subroutine](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/sparse-blas-level-2-and-level-3-routines/sparse-blas-level-2-and-level-3-routines-1/mkl-csrmv.html#mkl-csrmv) subroutine and supplying `'A'` to the first element in the [matrix descriptor array](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/sparse-blas-level-2-and-level-3-routines/interface-consideration.html).

Ok I managed to find the answer to my question when I started testing the general MKL Sparse BLAS matrix-vector multiplication in CSR format (`mkl_?csrmv`)

I learnt that there is a [character array](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/sparse-blas-level-2-and-level-3-routines/interface-consideration.html) that is used to describe the input matrix (`matdescra`). The first character in this array can be set to `'A'` which causes the subroutine to interpret the input matrix as skew-symmetric. For example (not necessarily a good one),

Given a matrix, A, and and vector, x,:

```
A = [ 0  1  2      x = [ 1
     -1  0  3            2
     -2 -3  0 ]           3 ]
```

The upper-triangle of `A` can be represented as

```
val = [1, 2, 3]
col = [2, 3, 3]
rowstart = [1, 3, 3]
rowend = [3 3 4]
```

and with the character array `matdescra = ['A', 'U', 'N', 'F']`,
The matrix-vector product is obtained by

```
call mkl_scsrmv('n', 3, 3, 1., matdescra, val, rowstart, rowend, x, 1., y
```

where the output (a vector) is added to the vector-array, `y`.